# Are smooth functions a Sobolev space?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

The main question is: is the following expression true? $$C^l \subset W^{l,p} \subset L^p$$

To expand: from what I know Sobolev space is a way to weaken the differentiability requirements for a function, being the space of the functions which are p-integrable and have p-integrable weak derivatives up to the l-th order. This seems a stronger requirement than just being $L^p$ but a softer one than being $C^l$, therefore the above claim, but I'm afraid there could be some pathological examples I'm not thinking of.

Comment: The constant function $f(x) = 1$ is smooth but not a $L^p$ integrable (say on $\mathbb R$).

Comment: I think that problems will come from unbounded domains (a function can be smooth but not be in $L^p$). The inclusion should be true for bounded domains though.

Comment: Other problems may come from domains with irregular boundary ...

Answer (score 1):

You can always construct a smooth function which is not in $L^p(\Omega)$ ( hence not in $W^{l,p}(\Omega)$ ) even for bounded $\Omega$ with regular boundary, just take a function which blow up ( enough ) near the boundary. But you can always approximate functions in $W^{l,p}(\Omega)$ by smooth functions.